# How to detect a key press once and use '!=' symbol?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to figure out how to increase the intensity of my shapes moving when holding the 'up' arrow key. When I hold space bar, I wanted my shapes to rumble based on the intensity, which I've done. What I also would like to do is be able to increase the intensity by pressing the 'up' arrow key once (NOTE: Once. Currently when I press the arrow key once, it loops way too fast and multiplies the intensity by like 5000x. I would like it just to add one number each time.) This is the code that does not work how I'd like.

```
import pygame
import random
import time



BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# Edit the intensity of the shake (Must be one number apart)
# Ex: a = -100, b = 101. A is negative, B is positive
a = -4
b = 5
up = 10
intensity = (a, b)

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 700)
        self.y = random.randrange(0, 500)
        self.height = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.width = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.x_change = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.y_change = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.color = random.sample(range(250), 4)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change


class Ellipse(Rectangle):
    pass

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change

my_list = []
for number in range(600):
    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_list.append(my_object)
for number in range(600):
    my_object = Ellipse()
    my_list.append(my_object)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for rect in my_list:
        rect.draw()
        rect.move()
    for rectElli in my_list:
        rectElli.draw()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            rectElli.y_change = random.randrange(a, b)
            rectElli.x_change = random.randrange(a, b)
            rectElli.move()
            print(a)
            print(b)
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and up / 10 == 1:
            up += 1
            a -= 1
            b -= -1
            print(a)
            print(b)
            print(up)
        if up / 10 != 1:
            up += 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

This is the code that worked before I wanted to add the increasing of intensity.

```
import pygame
import random
import time



BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# Edit the intensity of the shake (Must be one number apart)
# Ex: a = -100, b = 101. A is negative, B is positive
a = -4
b = 5
up = 10
intensity = (a, b)

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 700)
        self.y = random.randrange(0, 500)
        self.height = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.width = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.x_change = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.y_change = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.color = random.sample(range(250), 4)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change


class Ellipse(Rectangle):
    pass

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change

my_list = []
for number in range(600):
    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_list.append(my_object)
for number in range(600):
    my_object = Ellipse()
    my_list.append(my_object)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for rect in my_list:
        rect.draw()
        rect.move()
    for rectElli in my_list:
        rectElli.draw()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            rectElli.y_change = random.randrange(a, b)
            rectElli.x_change = random.randrange(a, b)
            rectElli.move()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is, that you do the increasing of the intensity in the `for`-loop which traverse the ellipses. So the intensity is not increased once, it is increased once per  ellipse.

If you don't want to increase the intensity in every 10th frame, then you've to verify if the increment the frame counter `up` in every frame, but you've to verify if it is divisible by 10. Verify if the remainder of an integral division by 10 is 0. Use the modulo operator (`%`) to calculate the remainder:

```py
if up % 10 == 0:
```

See the example, when <kbd>UP</kbd> is pressed, the the intensity increases and when it is released then the intensity returns to normal:

```py
while not done:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for rect in my_list:
        rect.draw()
        rect.move()
    for rectElli in my_list:
        rectElli.draw()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            rectElli.y_change = random.randrange(a, b)
            rectElli.x_change = random.randrange(a, b)
            rectElli.move()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        up += 1
        if up % 10 == 0:
            a -= 1
            b -= -1
    else:
        a, b = -4, 5

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```